# What is option -O3 for g++ and nvcc?

Tags: c++, compilation, cuda, nvcc

I'm new to nvcc and I've seen a library where compilation is done with option -O3, for g++ and nvcc.

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=--std=c++11 -O3
NVCC=nvcc
NVCCFLAGS=--std=c++11 -arch sm_20 -O3
```

What is -O3 doing ?

Comment: "I can't find any documentation on it." Have you tried `g++ --help` or `man g++` yet?

Comment: just so this doesn't happen to you again, when you google something that starts with a `-` character you should put it in quotes like `gcc "-O3"` because otherwise you tell google "search for gcc BUT NOT O3" instead. Also, try to differentiate between `0` and `O`

Comment: thanks, that's the mistake I did...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's optimization on level 3, basically a shortcut for
several other options related to speed optimization etc. (see link below).

> I can't find any documentation on it.

... it is one of the best known options:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/#options-for-altering-compiler-linker-behavior